# HTML Email Teamplate Issues SF

Tags: apex, email-template, visualforce-template

In the HTML email template I want to distinguish between internal and external user while sending any email. I tried using If loop and it worked for me but while I try to access certain merge fields values its not populating any results.

```
{!Receiving_User.Contact}
{!Receiving_User.ContactId}
{!Receiving_User.Division}
{!Receiving_User.Legacy_Username__c}  [Custom Field]
{!Receiving_User.Email}
{!Receiving_User.ProfileId}
```

I know receiving user takes the value from the contact, if so then how come my {!Receiving_User.username} gets populated. Also , is their any other way to distinguis between this two types users .

Below is the If loop i used which worked fine but since the above merge fields is not providing any value, it is not helping me any further.

```
{!IF(Receiving_User.ContactId=="",'abc', "2")}.
```

Any help. I need this urgent !

I put the same question in salesforce forums (https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F0000000BPz3IAG) for faster reply.

Comment: try using ISNULL(Receiving_User.ContactId) in your logic, instead of checking for blank.